# What is the strategy to find all non-negative tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ with a constraint of $a+b+c+d=9$ and $4a+2b+c-d=31$?

Tags: combinatorics, diophantine-equations

I am trying to solve the following problem

> Find the coefficient of $x^{31}$ in the expansion of $(x^4+x^2-\tfrac{x}{12}-\tfrac{1}{3x})^9$.

By using multinomial expansion below,

$$
(x^4+x^2-\tfrac{x}{12}-\tfrac{1}{3x})^9 =\sum_{a+b+c+d=9} {9 \choose {a,b,c,d}}(x^4)^a (x^2)^b \left(-\frac{x}{12}\right)^c \left(-\frac{1}{3x}\right)^d
$$

and with some algebraic manipulation, I need to find  all non-negative tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ with a constraint of $a+b+c+d=9$ and $4a+2b+c-d=31$.

With Mathematica, I did the following.

```
ClearAll[data]
data = Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[9, {4}, Range[0, 9]], 1];
Select[data, 4 #[[1]] + 2 #[[2]] + #[[3]] - #[[4]] == 31 &]
```

The solution is $\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 8 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

## Question

What is the strategy to find the tuples easily?

Comment: There are only $\binom 83=56$  four-tuples that sum to $9$, so it should be an easy search.  Note:  I'm not sure that this is easier than just expanding the initial product but, of course, either way is quite messy.

Comment: @lulu: 56 tuples, are you sure? There  are 220 tuples that sum to 9 in total.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I thought they had to be positive integers.  Yes, that does make the space larger.  Still, though...adding the constraints gives us $5a+3b+2c=40$ so it looks like we can quickly handle large $a$, cutting the space down considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding the equations, you get $c=20-(5/2)a-(3/2)b$ and by subtracting them, you get $d=(3/2)a+(1/2)b-11$.
Plot the lines $c=0$ and $d=0$ on the $(a,b)$ plane.  They, along with the $a$-axis and $b$-axis, bound the region where all four are nonnegative.
Select gridpoints within the region where $a$ and $b$ are eithwr both even or both odd.

Answer (score 1):

For the conditions $a+b+c+d=9$ and $4a+2b+c-d=31$, consider possible values of $a$ starting at 9 and working to $0$. We see that the only possibilities are
$a=8$ or $a=7$.

Case : $a=7$

$a=7,b=1,c=1,d=0$

Case : $a=8$

$a=8,b=0,c=0,d=1$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{cases}
a+b+c+d=9\\
4a+2b+c-d=31
\end{cases}

## Trial 1 (Failed)

Choose $a=9$ then the equations get reduced to
\begin{cases}
b+c+d=0\\
2b+c-d=-5
\end{cases}
No solution for $b$, $c$ and $d$.

## Trial 2 (Succeeded)

Choose $a=8$ then the equations get reduced to
\begin{cases}
b+c+d=1\\
2b+c-d=-1
\end{cases}
The only solution is $b=c=0$ and $d=1$.

## Trial 3 (Succeeded)

Choose $a=7$ then the equations get reduced to
\begin{cases}
b+c+d=2\\
2b+c-d=3
\end{cases}
The only solution is $b=c=1$ and $d=0$.

The following trials always fail. As I don't know how to prove with algebra, let list them all.

## Trial 4 (Failed)

Choose $a=6$ then the equations get reduced to
\begin{cases}
b+c+d=3\\
2b+c-d=7
\end{cases}
No solution.

## Trial 5 (Failed)

Choose $a=5$ then the equations get reduced to
\begin{cases}
b+c+d=4\\
2b+c-d=11
\end{cases}
No solution.

## Trial 6 (Failed)

Choose $a=4$ then the equations get reduced to
\begin{cases}
b+c+d=5\\
2b+c-d=15
\end{cases}
No solution.

## Trial 7 (Failed)

Choose $a=3$ then the equations get reduced to
\begin{cases}
b+c+d=6\\
2b+c-d=19
\end{cases}
No solution.

## Trial 8 (Failed)

Choose $a=2$ then the equations get reduced to
\begin{cases}
b+c+d=7\\
2b+c-d=23
\end{cases}
No solution.

## Trial 9 (Failed)

Choose $a=1$ then the equations get reduced to
\begin{cases}
b+c+d=8\\
2b+c-d=27
\end{cases}
No solution.

## Trial 10 (Failed)

Choose $a=0$ then the equations get reduced to
\begin{cases}
b+c+d=9\\
2b+c-d=31
\end{cases}
No solution.